# Simplest way to extract number between x in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to call "identify" from Imagick just once to reduce compute time but I am not familiar with bash. Currently in bash I have the following  code:

```
width=`identify -ping -format '%w' "$file"`
height=`identify -ping -format '%h' "$file"`
```

This is bad because it call, download, process same file twice. Then I found out that I actually can call "Identify" just one:

```
resolution=`identify -ping -format '%wx%h' "$file"`
```

but how do I separate the "resolution" string variable into two variable.

For example:

resolution returns: 1000x500

I then would like to separate 1000 as "a" and 500 as "b"

Please guide what command to separate the strings then I can research on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ resolution=$(echo '1000x500')
$ echo "${resolution%x*}"
1000
$ echo "${resolution#*x}"
500
```

Obviously Used `echo '1000x500'` in place of `identify -ping -format '%wx%h' "$file"` since I don't have the latter command.

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03 and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion